# gdm does not start after logout

Tags: 19.10, gdm

This problem came after logout Ubuntu. I got only a black screen with a cursor and no text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try force restart the laptop. Hold the power off button on your laptop till the screen goes off and on. Also try unplugging and plug-in back your laptop battery if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> you can change to a TTY - a terminal without gui. There you can login and type:

```
systemctrl status gdm
```

Then you get the information, what gsm (the loginscreen) is doing. You can even restart that service by

```
sudo systemctrl restart gdm
```

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> you can change back to the GUI.